# Not able to get namedExports for ReactDOM in commonJS plugin in rollup

Tags: reactjs, rollup

I am trying to include React and ReactDOM namedExports in Rollup.js using CommonJS plugin.

For me React object is proper but ReactDOM is undefined.

Want to what is the change needed and How React object is not empty

With below codein rollup.config.js i am getting React as object but ReactDOM is empty.

```
namedExports: {
'node_modules/react/react.js': 
['Children', 'Component', 'PropTypes', 'createElement'],
'node_modules/react-dom/index.js': ['render']

}
```

ReactDOM Object should be also defined and how this is working for React.

Even though i am not telling to use React

Answer (score 4):

**Update** just stumbled upon this much more concise and almost "automatic" solution shown in this [comment by TrySound](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs/issues/290#issuecomment-537683484). I just tried it out and it works as expected. Also I'd say it seems to be the preferred way [until React supports esm](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs/issues/290#issuecomment-562938023).

```js
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import * as react from 'react';
import * as reactDom from 'react-dom';
import * as reactIs from 'react-is';
import * as propTypes from 'prop-types';

export default {
  ...
   plugins: [
    ...
    commonjs({
      namedExports: {
        react: Object.keys(react),
        'react-dom': Object.keys(reactDom),
        'react-is': Object.keys(reactIs),
        'prop-types': Object.keys(propTypes),
      },
    }),
  ]
}
```

#### Origial answer

Hope you figured it out by now. For future reference to others and myself this is what's working for me:

```js
// note `rollup-plugin-commonjs` has been deprecated in favor of `@rollup/plugin-commonjs`
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  // [..] other configs like `input` & `output`
  plugins: [
    commonjs({
      include: 'node_modules/**',
      // left-hand side can be an absolute path, a path
      // relative to the current directory, or the name
      // of a module in node_modules
      namedExports: {
        'node_modules/react/index.js': [
          'cloneElement',
          'Component',
          'createContext',
          'createElement',
          'createRef',
          'forwardRef',
          'Fragment',
          'isValidElement',
          'lazy',
          'memo',
          'Profiler',
          'PureComponent',
          'StrictMode',
          'Suspense',
          'useCallback',
          'useContext',
          'useDebugValue',
          'useEffect',
          'useImperativeHandle',
          'useLayoutEffect',
          'useMemo',
          'useReducer',
          'useRef',
          'useState',
          'version',
        ],
        'node_modules/react-dom/index.js': [
          'findDOMNode',
          'render',
          'unmountComponentAtNode',
        ],
        'node_modules/react-dom/server.js': [
          'renderToStaticMarkup',
          'renderToString',
        ],
        'node_modules/react-is/index.js': [
          'AsyncMode',
          'ConcurrentMode',
          'ContextConsumer',
          'ContextProvider',
          'Element',
          'ForwardRef',
          'Fragment',
          'isAsyncMode',
          'isConcurrentMode',
          'isContextConsumer',
          'isContextProvider',
          'isElement',
          'isForwardRef',
          'isFragment',
          'isLazy',
          'isMemo',
          'isPortal',
          'isProfiler',
          'isStrictMode',
          'isSuspense',
          'isValidElementType',
          'Lazy',
          'Memo',
          'Portal',
          'Profiler',
          'StrictMode',
          'Suspense',
          'typeOf',
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
}
```

Not exactly sure it's the best approach and/or necessary/good to list (almost) all exports from those, but it works.

If that's right usage it could be packaged up Maybe I'll do that once I've figured out if this is the way to go.

Related links:
- [@rollup/plugin-commonjs README](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs#namedexports)
- [Comment by Rich Harris (Creator of Rollup)](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs/issues/211#issuecomment-337897124)